# Batch- Use if-else with forfiles recursively

Tags: date, batch-file, if-statement, batch-processing

I use `forfiles` command to check if the files from a directory have the actual date:

```
forfiles /p C:\copies /s /m *.bak /d 0 
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
  echo OK
) else (
  echo Non OK
  EXIT /%errorlevel%
)
```

But the `if-else statement` only works with the last file. If I use the `/c` parameter it works fine but I can't use the `else` to do other think:

```
/c "cmd /c echo @file is outdated."
```

What is the best way to use the if-else statement with forfiles?

Comment: What do you mean by "...only works with the last file"? I suppose `forfiles` will just reset the `ErrorLevel` if any files match the given criteria, and it will set the `ErrorLevel` in case *no* files are found...

Answer (score 2):

You can try first iterate the files and then to use forfiles:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /r "C:\copies" %%# in (*.bak) do (
  (forfiles /p "%%~dp#"  /m "%%~nx#" /d 0 )&&(
      echo ok
      color
  )||(
     echo not ok
     exit !errorlevel!
  )
)
```

Comment: You need to remove the `/s` option from the FORFILES command.

Comment: And the mask should be `%%~nx#`